# Mi algoritmo de ecuacion de segundo grado siempre me dice que debe ser mayor o igual a 0

Tags: javascript

Estoy reorganizando algunos proyectos que hice cuando estaba empezando a programar y uno de ellos es la ecuación de segundo grado programada en JavaScript. Lo que no entiendo es que no importa que numero coloque en los campos del algoritmo siempre me dice que el subradical debe ser mayor o igual a cero y no veo el error, agradecería la ayuda.

```js
    //Algoritmo Ecuación de 2do. Grado
    //Inicio 
        //{Declaración de variables}
        var a, b, c, subradical, x1, x2;
        //{Inicialización de variables}
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
        subradical = 0;
        x1 = 0;
        x2 = 0;
        a = parseFloat(prompt("Ingrese el valor de a: "));
        if (a==0){
            document.write("ERROR: el valor de a debe ser diferente de 0");
        }else{
            b = parseFloat(prompt ("Ingrese el valor de b:"));
            c = parseFloat (prompt("Ingrese el valor de c:"));
            subradical = b*b-4*a*c;
            if (subradical < 0){
                document.write("ERROR: La expresión subradical debe ser mayor o igual a 0");
            }else{
                x1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(subradical))/(2*a);
                x2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(subradical))/(2*a);
                document.write("x1="+ x1 +",x2 =" + x2);
            }
    
        }
    //Fin
```

Comment: intente con `1,5,4` y no me marco error podrias agregar lo que te sale?

Comment: yo intenté con 12, 35 y 15, y tampoco me marcó error. Ya intentaste hacer tus pruebas con valores que SI tengan resultado? (vaya, que hayas resuelto la ecuación a mano y te diera algún resultado). Porque por ejemplo. si insertas 1, 1 y 1, obviamente no va a funcionar, porque la ecuación x² + 1 + 1 = 0 no tiene solución.

Comment: Claro, no habia tomado en cuenta esos detalles. Seguramente todos los numeros con los que probe no tenian solucion. Gracias!